# showind data from xml files in c# with more flexibile way

Tags: c#, xml, xmlhttprequest

i want to show data from xml files like **xml api** of hotel packages. however i have some methods like `xmldocument()`... still having doubt of using most effective way to represent hotel data with good programming techniques. this is a web portal where i have to fetch data from remote xml file.

```
<results>
    <content>
        <fields>
            <field name="headlines"> This is headline </field>
            <field name="text"> This is text </field>
            <field name="url"> This is url </field>
        <fields>
    </content>
    <content>
        …
    </content>
    …
</results>
```

Comment: What is the question? What does this have to do with xmlhttprequest?

Answer (score 0):

[Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is a good place to start. As well as that MSDN page, there's a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoXML.aspx) tutorial that explains how to use Linq to XML.